# php files run in browser, but long scripts lead to attempted file download and script stoppage

Tags: php, zend-framework, mime-types

I've recently installed zend server (Zend Server CE (PHP 5.3)   5.6.0 SP4) on my local machine to support php / mysql site builds.

I have an existing and working site and have managed to download the php files and database to my local machine and get things (mostly) working after some tweaks.

My current issue has me stumped. I have two php scripts. Once reads a database of file locations and downloads each file to a local directory with a specific name. This take a short while and runs successfully. The 30 files are csv datafeed files around 1GB total.

The second script inserts each file into a MySql table (using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ....), makes a few changes, then inserts each one into a larger master table.

This script runs OK initially, the first table is inserted OK, changes made, then this data is inserted in the master table. Same with the second, third and 4th I have over 70,000 rows of data processed and inserted into my master table.

And then... The script stops running and I get a dialogue box asking where I would like to save the php file?!

I've looked around and there are a few fixes offered for the issue of a php script leading immediately to a save as dialogue box, solutions seem to be mostly clear cache, set a handler for the php file correctly, try another browser.

I added this to httpd.conf and restarted Apache with no success:

`
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>

    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

</FilesMatch>

AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

<IfModule dir_module>

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

</IfModule>
```

`

My scripts process and then fail, but only if they last 30 seconds or so. This happens in Chrome and Firefox and after entire cache has been cleared.

Can anyone suggest how the file would lead to the script processing but also triggering the download and how I can stop it?

Comment: Enable error logging and trace the error log. Also see http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: The download aspect is just dependent on what headers/content have already been sent when the error occurs I think.  Not unusual.  As hakre points out probably just need to up your time_limit and possibly memory limit.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting same issue. Have set:
'set_time_limit ( 15000 );
 error_reporting(E_ALL);'
No errors shown in browser or in php error log.
I upped the memory limit also 'memory_limit = 2048M;' in php.ini
'phpinfo()' confirms these new settings were in use.
Still can't see how the script would run then download halfway through... Cheers for the ideas tho'

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I never managed to identify the problem with the Zend Server. But...

I uninstalled Zend, and installed EasyPHP and it works fine.